# How do you keep track where an inherited method comes from

Tags: php, class, oop, object, inheritance

Considering this simple example of classes:

// father.php

```
class father {
    public function wallet () {}
}
```

// mother.php

```
class mother extends father { }
```

// daughter.php

```
class daughter extends mother { 

    public function shop {

        $this->wallet();

    }   
}
```

Is there a convention/coding practice that tells you quickly that `wallet()`  comes from class `father`?

This isn't a big deal but when reviewing old code (without an IDE) it's nice to know quickly where inherited methods come from.

Comment: You can read the code (laborious, but works), you can use IDE features (nice and quick) or you can programmatically inspect the class. That should be all you need. The last thing you'd want to do is require some conventional notation when writing `$this->wallet()` just so you can trace where it comes from.

Comment: Also, the politically correct implementation here would require multiple inheritance, not patriarchal inheritance. 

Answer (score 1):

Though seemingly trivial, one has to loop over sequence of parent's classes:

```
$seekMethod = 'wallet';
$stack = [];
foreach(class_parents('daughter') as $parent){
    foreach((new ReflectionClass($parent))->getMethods() as $method){
        if($seekMethod == $method->name){
            $stack[] = "{$method->class}::{$method->name}() in {$parent}";
            echo "Found ".end($stack);
        }
    }
}

echo "{$seekMethod} is defined in ".end($stack);
```

Will output something like:

```
Found father::wallet() in mother 
Found father::wallet() in father 
wallet is defined in father::wallet() in father
```

Or simpler, without respecting inheritance:

```
foreach((new ReflectionClass('daughter'))->getMethods() as $method){
    if($seekMethod == $method->name){
        echo "Found {$method->class}::{$method->name}";
    }
}
```

Will output e.g.

```
Found father::wallet
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance isn't the easiest to follow without an IDE (or a lot of documentation).

PHPDoc does have the @see tag which you could use as:

```
/**
* @see father::wallet()   For logic pertaining to wallet retrieval
*/
public function shop {

    $this->wallet();

}
```

Beyond that, you want to make sure your inheritance makes sense.  I'm sure this was just a quick example, but I don't see any reason why a daughter would ever extend a father.

A daughter could extend a Child, and in the Child, you could have the logic pertaining to pulling the wallet from a parent (or father).

Comment: The problem with annotating `daughter` is that implementations in `mother` may change, and then the comment is out of whack with reality…

Comment: Not to mention, this would be incredibly cumbersome to document every single inherited method usage, hence my note about "a lot of documentation".  I wouldn't recommend this route, but it is possible if you want to be thorough and you do take the time to keep the doc blocks updated on changes, as you'd probably want to look at this method anyways before making changes to mother::wallet() since this would be affected.